# Checkbox checked value binding

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, checked

The code below is what I have written for a checkbox. Not sure why this doesn't show the value as checked, even though its coming correctly from my JS file.

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: { value: person.id}, checked: $root.chosenPerson">
```

If the `chosenPerson` contains two values, these should be checked in the checkbox. This doesnt happen.

I also tried :

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr: { value: person.id}, checked: $root.chosenPerson">
```

And I also tried:

```html
<input type="checkbox" 
       data-bind="attr : { checked:$root.chosenPerson }, value : person.id" />
```

Nothing works in making the `chosenPerson` "checked".

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your binding should return true, so change it to this -

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: person.id}, checked: $root.chosenPerson() === $data">
```

Where chosenPerson is equal to the context of the input element.  If the element is not within the context of a person, just do

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="attr: { value: person.id}, checked: $root.chosenPerson() === person()">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not understand what is $root.chosenPerson() === person() in the second statement which you have provided. Basically , for me chosenPerson() comes from my JS file. Its a Knockout Array. But what is person() here? Please guide me. Thank You again.

Comment: @user2598808 person is an example of whatever is in your array.  If you are `foreach`ing over an array and using the checkbox inside of it just use the `$data` binding

Answer (score 4):

If your `chosenPerson` array contains integers, the value of the checkbox must also be an integer. This isn't possible using the `attr/value` binding because it just set the `value` attribute of the element, which will always be a string. Instead you should use the `checkedValue` binding, which can bind any type of value.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: person.id, checked: $root.chosenPerson">
```